# Random function covariance

Tags: signal-analysis, continuous-signals, covariance

I was studying signal processing and I was frequently asked to verify if a certain covariance is possible for a given random function. I tried to check by verifying the property to prove it:

${γ}_{xx}(τ) = {γ}_{xx}(t+τ,t)$

but didn't quite got anything.

For exemple, if we suppose $τ_0$ a given constant, how would I prove that I can have the following covariance (or not)?

${γ}_{xx}(τ) = exp(-(τ- τ_0)^2)$

Comment: Would you have an example of such a stochastic process that you should check? Because, honestly, all I can imagine is just actually writing down the autocovariance definition, inserting your knowledge of the process in there, and showing that it can (or cannot) be $\exp(-(\tau-\tau_0)^2)$.

Comment: Hi: Given your notation, ( and not to be picky but these things can be confusing so best to specific on terminology ) I think you mean auto-covariance. The only requirement for autocovariance is that $\gamma_{xx}(t + \tau, t) =  \gamma_{xx}(t, t + \tau)$ so, if you check that, that should be enough. But, as Marcus Muller mentioned, given the stochastic process, the autocovariance is defined so you can check it given the stochastic process.

Comment: The problems I've been trying to solve were actually just something like: "is this possible or not?". So, I was also kinda lost about that too. I think I did a mistake as I translated it from my French lectures; but the function I define as covariance is accuatly a "covariance statistique".

Comment: A simple example that is given is a signal of a 50Hz sinusoid which we can verify that it has a covariance of $γ_{xx}(t_1; t_2) = {A^2}/2 cos(2π{n_0}(t1 - t2))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different meanings for ${γ}_{xx}$ when you write stuff such as
$${γ}_{xx}(τ) = {γ}_{xx}(t+τ,t)$$
because on the LHS, the function ${γ}_{xx}$ has one argument while on the RHS it has two arguments. Be that as it may, a *very important property* of what you call the covariance but what most everyone else on dsp.SE would call the *autocovariance* function is that
$$\text{For all values of }\tau, |{γ}_{xx}(τ)| \leq {γ}_{xx}(0).\tag{1}$$
It is easy to verify that $\exp\left(-(\tau-t_0)^2\right)$ has value $\exp(-t_0^2)<1$ at $\tau=0$, and *larger* value $1$ at $\tau=t_0$, in contradiction of $(1)$, and so $\exp\left(-(\tau-t_0)^2\right)$ cannot possibly be a valid autocovariance (except, of course, for the special case of $t_0=0$).

Comment: Oh, indeed a good catch. The power of a signal is of course an upper limit for the autocov at any non-zero lag - Cauchy-Schwarz in L2, and you just use the classical $|<x(t),x(t+\tau)>|^2\leq|<x(t+\tau),x(t+\tau)>|\cdot|<x(t),x(t)>|$ with the knowledge that $<x(t+\tau),x(t+\tau)>$ is shift invariant, since in L2 inner product, the integral goes over all real numbers, thus $|<x(t),x(t+\tau)>|^2\leq|<x(t),x(t)>|^2$.

Comment: Note that LaTeX on a swipe phone keyboard is a special kind of hell.